# How to create geofence on DXMapControl?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, devexpress, bing-maps

I'm looking to create a fence on BingMap using DevExpress Map control, but I'm not getting how to accomplish this task. Any help will be appreciable.
Thank you.

Comment: Which DevExpress map control? WPF, Silverlight, WinForm, ASP.NET, Mobile, Win 8? By Geofence are you looking to draw a polygon or do you ant to have a background event that triggers when someone enters an area (Geofence)? If it is the second one what platform are you targeting?

Comment: @rbrundritt thank you for your response. Working on WPF. I want to provide option to draw a custom shape like circle, square.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress WPF MapControl supports different types of [vector elements](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10889). Vector Elements are displayed on a Map control by the [VectorLayer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfMapVectorLayertopic) object. You can either add  lines, circles, polygons, or another elements manually or add elements loaded from a Shapefile.

Related examples:
[How to customize the appearance of a map shape element](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4229)
[How to Load Shapes Data from a Shapefile](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3627)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a circle then create a MapEllipse and add it to the map:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfMapMapEllipseMembersTopicAll

Here is an example of adding a shape to the map using XAML: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument16806